# How to create a list with values located in a nested dictionary?

Tags: python

I am new to Python, so sorry in advance if my question seems too simple/foolish.

I want to extract all the values under a certain key inside a nested dictionary.

Let me explain the context of what I am trying to do. I have an excel file with 4 columns and 2 rows and created a nested dictionary out of it in the following manner:

```
openCL = open(path+'Client list.csv','r',encoding='utf-8')
readCL = csv.reader(openCL, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

clientlist = {}

for info in readCL:
    clientcode = info[0].replace('\ufeff', '')
    clientname = info[1].lower()
    mattercode = info[2]
    mattername = info[3]
    clientlist[clientname] = {'Client Code' : clientcode, 'Matter Code': mattercode, 'Matter Name': mattername}
```

The output for clientlist is the following:

```
{'hong kong co.': {'Client Code': '897', 'Matter Code': '0095', 'Matter Name': 'Incorporation of Brazilian Subsidiary'}, 'shanghai co.': {'Client Code': '965', 'Matter Code': '3569', 'Matter Name': 'Corporate Matters'}}
```

I want to retrieve all the values located inside the 'Matter Code' key; to do so I came up with the following for loop:

```
matter_codes_only = []

for val in [x.values() for x in clientlist.values()]:
    matter_codes_only.append(clientlist[clientname].get('Matter Code'))
```

However, the output I receive is the following:

```
In: matter_codes_only
Out: ['3569', '3569']
```

For some reason my loop duplicates one of the values and leaves out the other value (i.e., '0095'). Any thoughts on what am I missing here? Suggestions on a more efficient way to achieve my desired outcome are more than welcome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a list comprehension:

```
>>> d = {'hong kong co.': {'Client Code': '897', 'Matter Code': '0095', 'Matter Name': 'Incorporation of Brazilian Subsidiary'}, 'shanghai co.': {'Client Code': '965', 'Matter Code': '3569', 'Matter Name': 'Corporate Matters'}}
>>> [v['Matter Code'] for v in d.values()]
['0095', '3569']
```

Comment: But I won't have a list with the 'Matter Code' values with this right? I am going to need a list with these values further in my code.

Comment: @gcqhk19 I don't understand, `[v['Matter Code'] for v in d.values()]` *is* a list?

Comment: oops, noobie confusion =). Assigned a variable for your suggestion, not quite sure the concept but it worked perfectly! Thanks @RoadRunner!

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
In [1]: d = {'hong kong co.': {'Client Code': '897', 'Matter Code': '0095', 'Matter Name': 'Incorporation of Brazilian
   ...: Subsidiary'}, 'shanghai co.': {'Client Code': '965', 'Matter Code': '3569', 'Matter Name': 'Corporate Matters'}
   ...: }

In [2]: l = []

In [9]: for v in d.values():
   ...:     for key,val in v.items():
   ...:         if 'Matter Code' in key:
   ...:             l.append(v[key])
   ...:
   ...:

In [10]: l
Out[10]: ['0095', '3569']
```

**Explanation**: The dictionary values for `d` are also dicts again. So, we look for the key "Matter Code" in the dicts and append its value to an empty list `l`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but am getting this error:
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Any ideas?

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-ee89e515fa07> in <module>()
      2     for key,val in val.items():
      3         if 'Matter Code' in key:
----> 4             matter_codes_only.append(val[key])

TypeError: string indices must be integers